# Iterate through String with multiple lines

Tags: java, string, groovy, loops

I got some data:

```
def data = "# some useless text\n"+
        "# even more\n"+
        "finally interesting text"
```

How can I get the "interesting part" of that? So basically all lines, NOT starting with #.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One Groovy option would be:

```
def data = '''# some useless text
             |# even more
             |finally interesting text'''.stripMargin()

List lines = data.split( '\n' ).findAll { !it.startsWith( '#' ) }

assert lines == [ 'finally interesting text' ]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
data.eachLine {
    if (!it.startsWith( '#' )
        println it
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to get substrings then check each one starts with "#" or not.
For example:

```
String[] splitData = data.split("\n");
for (String eachSplit : splitData) {
  if (!eachSplit.startWith("#")) {
    print(eachSplit);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How's about splitting the string with \n character via the [split function](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html)

Now you can just test each string if it starts with # or not via `String.startsWith("#") .`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution by using Groovy's meta programming feature (http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses):

```
def data = "# some useless text\n"+
    "# even more\n"+
    "finally interesting text"

String.metaClass.collectLines = { it ->
    delegate.split('\n').findAll it
}

def result = data.collectLines{ !it.startsWith( '#' )}

assert result == ["finally interesting text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string based on the newline character (\n) and then ignore the lines that start with "#".

```
String[] lines = data.split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    if (line.startsWith("#") {
        continue;
    }
    //Do stuff with the important part
}
```

Note that this is pure Java.

Comment: this will split on the literal `"\n"`, not the newline character `\n`

Answer (score 0):

A regexp-based solution that does not require to convert the input string into a list is:

```
def data = '''\
# some useless text
# even more
finally interesting text'''

assert data.replaceAll(/#.*\n/, '') == 'finally interesting text'
```

If you need to split the input into lines anyways, you can still use regexps if you want to, using the [`Collection#grep`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#grep%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
assert data.split('\n').grep(~/[^#].*/) == ['finally interesting text']
```

PS: Regexps FTW! =P