# How to print each element of Multi-line String Parameter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've Pipeline job in Jenkins (v2.7.1) where I'd like to print each element of Multi-line String parameter (`Params`) with 3 strings in each line: *Foo*, *Bar*, *Baz* as an input.

So I've tried the following syntax (using [`split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454913) and `each`):

```
Params.split("\\r?\\n").each { param ->
    println "Param: ${param}"
}
```

but it fails with:

> `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`: Calling public static java.lang.Object
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(java.lang.Object,groovy.lang.Closure) on a CPS-transformed closure is not yet supported ([JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481)); encapsulate in a @NonCPS method, or use Java-style loops
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.GroovyClassLoaderWhitelist.checkJenkins26481(GroovyClassLoaderWhitelist.java:90)

which suggest to *encapsulate in a @NonCPS method, or use Java-style loops*.

---

So I've tried to *encapsulate in a @NonCPS method* like:

```
@NonCPS
def printParams() {
    Params.split("\\r?\\n").each { param ->
        println "Param: ${param}"
    }
}
printParams()
```

but it fails with:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods println groovy.lang.Closure java.lang.Object

Without the function (as per first example), adding `@NonCPS` at the beginning it complains about *unexpected token*.

---

I also tried Java-style syntax as suggested by using *for* operator (similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14449414/55075)):

```
String[] params = Params.split("\\r?\\n")
for (String param: params) {
    println "Param: ${param}"
}
```

which seems to work in plain Groovy, but it fails in Jenkins with:

> `java.io.NotSerializableException`: java.util.AbstractList$Itr
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)

---

Which syntax I should use to make it work?

Comment: have you tried to wrap it into @NonCPS ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it, I've added `@NonCPS` at the beginning, but it complains about *unexpected token*.

Comment: in a way like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636017/jenkins-groovy-how-to-call-methods-from-noncps-method-without-ending-pipeline . The question itself, not the answer. @NonCPS is smth. like python decorator

Comment: I've updated question showing code with @NonCPS which also fails.

Comment: Now you are hitting sandbox security with it. Proceed to Jenkins management to permit this method access or disable sandbox security for your job

Comment: Btw, _NotSerializableException_ is also about CPS

Comment: Disabling *Use Groovy Sandbox* option for the 2nd example with `@NonCPS` works fine. So if you could wrap it into answer, would be great. Is disabling sandbox necessary to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works fine when disabling a *Use Groovy Sandbox* option and adding `@NonCPS` helper method. Alternatively, as suggested by [@agg3l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195720/how-to-print-each-element-of-multi-line-string-parameter#comment67657865_40195720), proceed to *Jenkins management* to permit this method access.

So the working code is (same as the 2nd example):

```
@NonCPS
def printParams() {
    Params.split("\\r?\\n").each { param ->
        println "Param: ${param}"
    }
}
printParams()
```

Comment: Alternatively, add your printParams method to a Global Shared Library (see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries) and you don't need to add anything to the scriptApproval

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post but this is my way to do it, hopefully help anyone else

```
params.readLines().each {
                            println it
                            if (it) {
                                // if you want to avoid make operation with empty lines
                            }
                        }
```