# Groovy: Read a line from a text file into an array using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Context: 
I'm writing a jenkins file in which i want to read an `Input_params.txt` file, search for a keyword then, print the values of the keyword into an array and then print each element of the array.

The contents of input params (format is `"KEY:VALUE"`) file are:

```
sh> cat Input_params.txt
SOME_DETAILS:1234-A0;1456-B1;2456-B0;3436-D0;4467-C0
```

Step-1: Store the SOME_DETAILS in an array:

```
Integer[] testArray = ["1234-A0", "1456-B1", "2456-B0" , "3436-D0" , "4467-C0"]
```

Step-2: print the elements of the array sequentially. For example:

```
testArray.each {
println "chip num is ${it}"
}
```

Sample code:

```
println ("Check if the "Key:Value" is present in the Input_params.txt \n");
if ( new File("$JobPath/Input_params.txt").text?.contains("SOME_DETAILS"))
{
   println ("INFO: "Key:Value" is present in the info_file.txt \n");
  >>>>> Code to write the "value" of line with key "SOME_DETAILS" into an array here.. <<<<< 
}
```

I need help in writing the Code to write the "value" of line with key "SOME_DETAILS" into an array.

Comment: is it the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158849/groovy-regex-to-filter-out-keyvalue-pair-and-store-in-an-array/44160636#44160636

Comment: Hi @dagett, the question is slightly different here..

Answer (score 1):

```
def testArray=[]
new File("/11/tmp/1.txt").splitEachLine("[:;]"){line->
    if(line[0]=='SOME_DETAILS')testArray=line[1..-1]
}
println testArray
```

Comment: Jenkins Pipeline blacklist the use of new File()

Comment: file path:/11/tmp/1.txt
Content inside file must be in this Format:
SOME_DETAILS:1234-A0;1456-B1;2456-B0;3436-D0;4467-C0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
def theFile = new File("$JobPath/Input_params.txt")

def linesWithDetails = theFile.findAll {
    it.contains 'SOME_DETAILS'
}
```