# accessing the data of multi-line string parameter in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am passing a **multi-line string parameter using the option "this project is parameterized"** with content similar to

```
{"name"="aaaa", "url" = "xxxx"},
{"name"="bbbb", "url" = "yyyy"}
```

Following is the piece of code through which **I am able to get the each element**:

```
node ('docker-maven-slave')
{
  def string = params.details.split("\n") 
  echo "size is "+string.size()  
  for (i =0; i < string.size(); i++)
  { 
    echo string[i]
  }
}
```

**How do I access the specific value of each element? Like "name" and "url"**.

Is this the right approach for the such requirement? If not please suggest me the appropriate one.

Tried the same way that is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195720/how-to-print-each-element-of-multi-line-string-parameter):

```
@NonCPS    
def params() 
{
    params.details.split("\n").each {
        param -> println "${param}"
    } 
}
stage 'read-string'
node ('docker-maven-slave')
{

    params()
  //echo("${string.name}")

}
```

Comment: You have the response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195720/how-to-print-each-element-of-multi-line-string-parameter

Comment: yeah tried that as well, the result is not what I am expecting. Attaching the code.

Comment: have you think about the possibility of using the file parameter and passing a json file for example and to parse it using the JsonSlurper class?

Comment: I agree that using file parameter may work, but to provide more flexibility to the user, need to pass the parameters while building the job.

Comment: Have you disabled the "Use Groovy Sandbox" option of the pipeline when have you tested with the @NonCPS scope? You are using the same name for the function and the object from which you are calling to details method (params)

Comment: Yes, disabled as suggested