# Not able to split string in groovy DSL and there is no multi-line

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to split a URL http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/sub1/file.zip in groovy DSL of Jenkins. It is a single line string. But following code does not work

```
String[] arr= string_var.split('/');  
String[] arr=string_var.split('\\/');
```

It does not split it and returns itself in arr[0].
I am not sure if it is a bug. Please let me know if any other way is there in groovy to get "sub1" from URL string.

Comment: Duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197015/4279361

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print each element of Multi-line String Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195720/how-to-print-each-element-of-multi-line-string-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you doing DSL script correctly? As the groovy code looks to be OK.
Try to skip declaring types

```
def url_str = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/sub1/file.zip'
def sub = url_str.split('/')[-2]
println(sub)
```

in one line:

```
println('http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/sub1/file.zip'.split('/')[-2])
```

no split, indexes:

```
def url_str = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/sub1/file.zip'
int[] indexes = url_str.findIndexValues {it == "/"}
println url_str.substring(indexes[-2] + 1, indexes[-1])
```

Comment: That split() itself is not working. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What version of groovy do you use? Do you have any exceptions, errors?

Comment: try without split, I added variant.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your code inside a 'script' tag of DSL language like the following piece of code:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        script {
          def string_var = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/sub1/file.zip"
          String[] arr= string_var.split('/');
          println "${arr[0]}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Executing code above I get this result on the console:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
http:
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Thus, giving the expected 'http:' String

Another Groovy way to get the string 'sub1' (regex):

```
String s = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/sub1/file.zip"

def match = s =~ /(sub1)/
if (match.size() > 0) { // If url 's' contains the expected string 'sub1'
  println match[0][1]
  // Or do something with the match
}​
```

Comment: In first solution I am getting error as not able to find method and 2nd solution won't work as I need to find value "sub1". So match won't work.

Comment: I have updated the first method with the full example it it helps. That works for me on my local Jenkins (gives green every time I run it). Maybe your full script has something missing, watch the pipeline sections you use.

Comment: I have a class for fetching Artifactory using Jenkins plugin and in a method I am trying to split a string.